# How to handle DB Migrations in serverless environment? NodeJS+Lambda

Tags: node.js, database, aws-lambda, migration

Im coming from a .NET background(using EF). Im migrating my website to using NodeJS Lambda functions.

With EF, I would use code-first migrations, meaning EF generates the migration files for me. I've seen there are several NodeJS packages do do have migrations(TypeOrm,Seequalize,etc). What I don't understand about this is how would I handle migrations(for example, If I add a column or change the model) in a serverless, and microservices environment, since the is no central location that the migration files would be stored?